# How to draw rectangle border using rectangle class in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, rectangles

Quick question, can I make a border for the rectangle using the rectangle class also that I have drawn on the screen. I'm using libgdx and java developing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw the Rectangle with a ShapeRenderer:

```
private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
private Rectangle rectangle;

@Override
public void show() {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,10,10);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    shapeRenderer.begin();
    shapeRenderer.rect(rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY(), rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
    shapeRenderer.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    shapeRenderer.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's more understandable than the others provided in the internet. I tried using shaperenderer before but there were samples that were really hard to follow.